# How to find the SQL_ID of a sql statement efficiently?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, performance, plsql

I am trying to do a case and whitespace insensitive search on [V$SQLSTAT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2131.htm#REFRN30396)'s SQL_FULLTEXT column so that I can find the SQL_ID associated with a given sql. My solution is way too inefficient.

I limited the search to the first 1000 characters just to try and make it faster, but it is still very slow.

```
DECLARE
  given_sql     CLOB;
  id            VARCHAR2(13);
  smaller_sql   VARCHAR2(1000);
  replace_chars VARCHAR2(6);
BEGIN
    given_sql:= 'long sql statement'
    -- whitespace characters used in TRANSLATE
    replace_chars:= chr(32) || chr(9) || chr(10) || chr(11) || chr(12) || chr(13);
    -- taking substring of given_sql
    smaller_sql:= dbms_lob.substr(given_sql, 1000, 1);
    -- Calling translate to remove extra whitespace and then calling LOWER()
    smaller_sql:= LOWER(TRANSLATE(smaller_sql, replace_chars, ' '));

    -- In the WHERE clause I apply the same process that I applied to smaller_sql to the 
    -- SQL_FULLTEXT column.
    SELECT SQL_ID INTO ID
    FROM V$SQLSTATS stats
    WHERE dbms_lob.compare(LOWER(TRANSLATE(dbms_lob.substr(SQL_FULLTEXT, 1000, 1), replace_chars, ' ')), smaller_sql) = 0;
    dbms_output.put_line(ID);
END;
```

Essentially, I want to do a efficient whitespace, and case insensitive search on a CLOB column.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Not sure how I can provide sample data since the V$SQLSTATS view is filled based upon the sql statements executed.

Comment: v$sqlstats.sql_fulltext is a CLOB, so there is an overhead to loading it. The sql_text column might be more efficient for checking the first 1000 characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you can do it with the first 1000 characters, use the sql_text column of the v$sqlarea view, that should speed things up.